# SQL - How to count number of data in certain year?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to count the number of orders made in the year 2019 however I keep getting an error

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

The SQL that I tried running is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Order_tab
WHERE Order_Date = '%2019';
```

The table format is

```
create table Order_tab 
(   
    Order_ID number (11,0) not null,
    Order_Date date DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    Customer_ID number (11,0),

    constraint Order1_PK 
        primary key (Order_ID),

    constraint Order1_FK 
        foreign key (Customer_ID) references Customer_tab(Customer_ID)
);
```

and data that I have added to that table is:

```
insert into Order_tab values (1010, '06/12/2017', 5);
insert into Order_tab values (1011, '06/12/2017', 1);
insert into Order_tab values (1012, '06/12/2017', 5);
insert into Order_tab values (1013, '06/12/2017', 1);
insert into Order_tab values (1014, '06/12/2017', 2);
insert into Order_tab values (1015, '06/13/2017', 5);
insert into Order_tab values (1016, '06/13/2017', 1);
insert into Order_tab values (1017, '07/20/2019', 12);
insert into Order_tab values (1018, '08/03/2018', 11);
insert into Order_tab values (1019, '01/29/2019', 6);
insert into Order_tab values (1020, '02/14/2019', 9);
insert into Order_tab values (1021, '03/24/2019', 11);
insert into Order_tab values (1022, '06/14/2019', 15);
insert into Order_tab values (1023, '10/31/2019', 7);
insert into Order_tab values (1024, '01/31/2020', 7);
insert into Order_tab values (1025, '10/05/2020', 14);
insert into Order_tab values (1026, '01/01/2020', 13);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order_date` isn't a string but a `date`. So the engine tries to upcast `'%2019'` to a `date` in order execute the comparison. But `'%2019'` isn't a valid `date` representation.

Plus the comparison doesn't make sense in the way you used it, even if `order_date` was a string (which would be wrong). You may have wanted `LIKE` not `=`.

Anyway, use a range comparison.

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM order_tab
       WHERE order_date >= to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
             AND order_date < to_date('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

That has the advantage that it can use an index on `order_date`, whereas methods extracting the year from the `order_date` and comparing that to 2019 (as number or string) cannot.

Comment: Your comment about index is not quite right. If there is an index on date, Oracle will only read from the index regardless, because the query only needs the date - it doesn't need any other value, and it doesn't need to consider the rows where the date is NULL.

Comment: @mathguy: It might only use the index but it has to scan all of the index and apply the extraction of the year before it can decide whether the item should be counted or not (unless it's an FBI with the extraction of course). Otherwise it can quickly find the first matching item and then the last item.

Comment: Yup - now we are in perfect agreement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following filter:

```
to_char(order_date, 'yyyy') = '2019'
```

Or a better one:

```
order_date between to_date('2019.01.01', 'yyyy.mm.dd') and to_date('2019.12.31', 'yyyy.mm.dd')
```

Comment: The "better way" will miss data from 31 December with time-of-day after midnight (00:00), because the date value as you wrote it returns midnight at the beginning of the day.

Comment: The second one is better. You can create and index on order_date, and the query will be faster.

Comment: I didn't say it's not better, I said it's wrong in some cases (specifically, if order_date stores the time-of-day of each order, not just the truncated date).

Comment: You are right, but Joon Hong Lee used only the date part. So the upper bound sholud be to_date('2019.12.31 23:59:59', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss')

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a date (in the proper, DATE data type) to a string. Oracle will attempt to convert your string '%2019' to a date - which, obviously, doesn't make sense.

To fix this: EXTRACT(YEAR FROM <date_expression>) returns the year in NUMBER data type, which you can then compare to 2019 (not to a string!) There are other ways, but this is probably the simplest.